# How do I call on an "dependency injected" JavaScript function from a template?

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I am using a module pattern, such as RequireJS, and I send in module A into module B.

Now inside my module I want to generate HTML using a template engine, but for sake of the question, lets say I create the HTML-string manually. In that HTML-string, I want to create a button that calls on a function provided by the module "a".

But I clearly can't just do:

```
define( [ "a.js" ], function( a ) {

    var html = "<button onclick='a.myfunction();'>Click me!</button>";

} );
```

How do I do that? Cross from JavaScript into "HTML-String", when I can't call of global functions, since its all module-based?

```
define( [ "a.js" ], function( a ) {

    var html = "<button onclick='*** HERE I WANT TO CALL A FUNCTION PROVIDED WITH A***'>Click me!</button>";

} );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use event delegation by means of [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
define(["a"], function (a) {

    var html = "<button>Click me!</button>";

    $("#buttonContainer").on("click", "button", a.myfunction);

});
```

Where buttonContainer is a container for your template that already exists on the page.

Comment: I know I can add the event via JavaScript manually afterwards - but doesn't break the whole idea of using a template language + engine?

Comment: @corgrath This suggestion is way better than inline event handlers.

Comment: @corgrath I don't see any problem here. In any case your module is responsible to generate an HTML, so why not to hook event handlers right after? If you still want to use button's `onclick` event inline I believe you can do something like this in your template: `<button onclick='require(["a"], function(a) { a.myfunction(); })'>Click me!</button>` But I won't do that - it's ugly and inefficient...